# Disable the focus event on input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with an auto-complete input field. When there are 3 
 characters in the input it fires an event and i don't want this to happen.
The input have `onfocus=//do something` parameter.

I've tried `event.preventDefault()`, `stopPropagation`, `return false` but none works

Comment: Please share the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the input's onFocus attribute:

`$('input').removeAttr('onFocus');`